# How to properly update a row in ag grid so undo/redo works

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an `ag-grid` table in react that pulls from two different data. The `BOOKS_COLLECTION` is an array of books with their titles and authors, and the `USERS_COLLECTION` is an array of users with a `ratings` property. The `ratings` property is an array of the book `ids` as well as that specific `user`'s rating for the book.

The `ag-grid` UI is responsible for editing the data. It uses a `select`-type editor with predefined options. The admin can change the rating of a user through the grid. My `valueSetter` function is as follows:

```
valueSetter: (params: ValueSetterParams) => {
  console.log('valueSetter: ', params);
  // doesnt exist yet in the ratings array
  if (!params.data.ratings.find((rating) => rating.bookId === book.id)) {
    params.data.ratings.push({
      bookId: book.id,
      rating: params.newValue,
    });
    return true;
  } else {
    // already exists in the ratings array
    const index = params.data.ratings.findIndex(
      (rating) => rating.bookId === book.id
    );

    if (params.data.ratings[index].rating !== params.newValue) {
      params.data.ratings[index] = {
        ...params.data.ratings[index],
        rating: params.newValue,
      };

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
},
```

I am also trying to get the `undo/redo` function of the `ag-grid` to work, but unfortunately, the `undoStack` and `redoStack` isn't recording the changes properly, therefore my buttons dont work as intended.

I have read that `ag-grid` handles the `undoRedoService` internally, so I can't really control that. I have a suspicion that because I am directly mutating the `params.data` in the `valueSetter` function, the `undo/redo` doesn't work properly.

Here is a working sample in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8zrumn?file=src%2FApp.tsx), thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ag-grid quite a bit, but have never used the undo/redo feature.

But I believe that your use of a valueSetter function is probably disabling the undo/redo.

I personally feel that this is as it should be, and that because the data is presumably part of your application's state, you are correct to use a valueSetter instead of allowing the grid to directly update your data.

Similarly, I recommend that you implement undo/redo yourself - this would update your state, which the grid would then render.

Comment: how do you go about editing the table's data? do you use the `valueParser`?

Comment: If you have your data stored separately from the grid, and have that data bound to the grid via it's  rowData property, then you would use your valueSetter method to update your data, and the grid will re-render, showing the new value.